# Would calculating the nth prime ruin encryption?

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm sure there is some proof that the nth prime can be found. But if we knew, would encryption that relies on primes be easy to decrypt?

Comment: An ill posed question [Finding the n-th prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951481/finding-the-n-th-prime-number) on Math.

Comment: TL;DR, only one cryptosystem in common use is based off primes, and we're phasing away from it anyway. And even then, it's based on the difficulty of *factoring* primes which is not necessarily made easier by being able to find the $n$th prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The only plausibly relevant major cryptosystems involving that are RSA-based cryptosystems.  A typical RSA prime is chosen uniformly at random from 1024-bit primes, of which there are $\pi(2^{1024}) - \pi(2^{1023}) \approx 2^{1014} - 2^{1013} = 2^{1013}$ possibilities, by the prime-counting approximation $\pi(x) \approx x/\!\log x$.  Even if you could efficiently find the 1762496654486650458301017412708452577168455321425338564295164204627851827809673950656701400197184589192372578810839228796442397889449007625305174377608286256232618793314981228756675796669238641660676263338471020306341778397911556529236704830386308649499298417719554769934355960770722959180457300530690137<sup>th</sup> one, for example, that wouldn't help you to guess which prime I picked.  You don't even have a hope of guessing which of the $2^{256}$ ChaCha keys I'm using, and there are a lot fewer of those.

Answer (score 1):

This is for completeness  and a complement to the nice answer above.

The $n^{th}$ prime number $p_n$ is **not known** for large $n$. The best unconditional bounds (i.e., without assuming unproved hypotheses such as the Riemann Hypothesis)  are are due to Dusart 
$$
n\left(\ln n+ \ln\ln n-1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2.1}{\ln n}\right)\leq p_n
\leq n\left(\ln n+ \ln\ln n-1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}\right),
$$
for $n\geq 688~383.$ This gives you an interval of size roughly 
$$\frac{n}{10 \ln n}\approx \frac{X}{10 \ln X \ln(X/\ln X)},$$ say around $X=2^{1024}.$

Magma tells me this value of $X$ yields an interval of length

> 36016401202093992734848699077520151544037300347215601448904318847226665527162111326023510565646939754194973835732156904989863338439213156939387133301740931734002194925153143466001030912699711055456251922934167058148794848690488514642661673725822399003877461223241027943589779640700089648544847778283520

Comment: What is specific about the 688383 and 1024-bit RSA? the \approx part is not clear for me. Also, [Bounds for n-th prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime)

Comment: The stronger bounds apply for this $n$ or larger due to techniques used. These are the strongest known. If $p_n=X$ then $n$ is approximately $X/\log X$.